# Radio buttons com simple_form nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Preciso configurar um *input* `radio` em um *simple form* com associação.

Tô seguindo a [documentação](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models), mas a dificuldade está sendo em renderizar o `radio` da forma certa. Ao invés de apresentar o conteúdo da associação ele apresenta um `array` de *YES* e *NO* para cada registro.

### Meus models:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answer_options
  belongs_to :page
end

class AnswerOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

### Meu código está assim:

```
- @page.questions.each do |question|
  h1 = question.title
  h5 = question.description

  = simple_form_for question do |f|
    = f.error_notification

    .form-inputs
      = f.simple_fields_for :answer_options do |ff|
        = ff.input :content, label: false, as: :radio_buttons

    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success'
```

O engraçado é que se deixo o campo sem o `as: :radio_buttons` ele traz o conteúdo certinho mas no formato de input text, quando na verdade eu preciso apresentar no formato `radio`.